# Get string length in batch

Tags: batch-file

It's a simple question I guess, but I am only able to find answers to complex situations.
My scenario is that I have a variable named AAA that has no spaces, no special characters, only letters, numbers, and maybe underscores.  I need to check that the length of AAA is not bigger than 16 characters  (16 chars or less is ok).

How can I achieve this in batch?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if "%AAA:~16%" == "" echo "Length is not bigger than 16 characters."
```

Or

```
if not "%AAA:~16%" == "" echo "Length is bigger than 16 characters."
```

Comment: thank you for your fast response. this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

here you have a few functions that calculate the string lenght: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=424.

So to check if he string length is bigger than 16:

```
@echo off
set AAA=something

call :strlen0.3 AAA strlen
 if %strlen% GTR 16 (
    echo has more than 16 characters
 ) else (
    echo has less than 16 characters
 )

 exit /b 0


:strlen0.3  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%A in (2187 729 243 81 27 9 3 1) do (
    set /A mod=2*%%A
    for %%Z in (!mod!) do (
        if "!s:~%%Z,1!" neq "" (
            set /a "len+=%%Z"
            set "s=!s:~%%Z!"

        ) else (
            if "!s:~%%A,1!" neq "" (
                set /a "len+=%%A"
                set "s=!s:~%%A!"
            )
        )
    )
  )
  endlocal & if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo **%len%**
exit /b
```